# PHP script to display images from folder

Tags: php

Hi I have security cam that uploads via ftp to my server and I want to show last images as slideshow but I can't manage it to work. I have this code

```
$base_path = 'wp-content/uploads/camer/10.121.0.202';
$latest_date_folder = scandir($base_path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest_folder = scandir($base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0], SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$directory = '../" . $base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_folder[0] . ';     
try {       
      
    echo '<div id="myslides">'; 
    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;   
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '"/>';  
        }
    }   
    echo '</div>';
}   
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';   
}
?>
```

I am still getting 'No images found for this slideshow.'
But when I try this code

```
$latest1_date_folder = scandir($base1_path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest1_folder = scandir($base1_path  . "/" . $latest1_date_folder[0], SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest1_file = scandir($base1_path  . "/" . $latest1_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest1_folder[0] , SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);

echo "<img src='../" . $base1_path  . "/" . $latest1_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest1_folder[0] . "/" . $latest1_file[0] . "' />";
```

It displays last image normally. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

> I am using wordpress plugin phpcode snippets

Comment: Rather than saying "no images found" you may want to look at why the exception is being thrown. Did you read documentation for DirectoryIterator to see when the constructor might throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your directory variable is wrong!
you should write like this

```
$directory = '../'. $base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_folder[0];
```

Comment: I completly changed it, I set on my cam that now it uploads only to one folder. And it is lot easier now. Thanks for help